# public static final int 13687=0x7f020000; Error

Tags: android

I am creating simple calculation program/app on android here's the auto generated error comes
 public static final int 13687=0x7f020000;

here's the code:
 src>java :

```
public class FirstAct extends Activity {
int counter;
int i;
Button plus,minus,x,Divide;
TextView Show;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
        counter =0;
        i=1;
        plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xadd); //buttons in java
        minus =(Button) findViewById(R.id.xsub);
        x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xmultiply);
        Divide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.xdivide);
        Show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xtv2);


        plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;

            }
        });

       minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                Show.setText("Total ="+counter);
            }
        });

      x.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter*=i;
                i++;
                Show.setText("Total ="+counter);
            }
        });
      Divide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter/=i;
                i++;
            Show.setText("Total ="+counter);
            }
        }); 

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

here's gen>R>java code

```
public static final int activity_horizontal_margin=0x7f050000;
        public static final int activity_vertical_margin=0x7f050001;
    }
        public static final class drawable {
        public static final int 13687=0x7f020000; //error here it is?? WHY
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020001;
    }
    public static final class id {
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f090006;
        public static final int xadd=0x7f090001;
        public static final int xdivide=0x7f090004;
        public static final int xmultiply=0x7f090003;
        public static final int xsub=0x7f090002;
        public static final int xtv1=0x7f090000;
        public static final int xtv2=0x7f090005;
    }
    public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_first=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class menu {
        public static final int first=0x7f080000;
    }
    public static final class raw {
        public static final int sunrahahai=0x7f040000;
    }
    public static final class string {
        public static final int Total=0x7f060003;
        public static final int Wel=0x7f060002;
        public static final int action_settings=0x7f060001;
        public static final int app_name=0x7f060000;
        public static final int del=0x7f060005;
        public static final int div=0x7f060006;
        public static final int mul=0x7f060007;
        public static final int sum=0x7f060004;
    }
    public static final class style {
        /** 
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.


            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

         */
        public static final int AppBaseTheme=0x7f070000;
        /**  Application theme. 
 All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. 
         */
        public static final int AppTheme=0x7f070001;
    }
}
```

Here's the XML CODE:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FirstAct" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xtv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Wel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/xadd"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sum"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/xsub"
        android:layout_width="147dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/del"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/xmultiply"
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:text="@string/mul"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/xdivide"
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/div"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xtv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
        android:text="@string/Total"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You apparently have a drawable resource named `13687.png`, `13687.jpg`, etc. Rename that so that the file's basename (name without extension) is a valid Java data member name (letters, numbers, and underscores allowed, but cannot begin with a number).

Comment: Thats true, its name cannot begin with a digit.

Comment: public static final int value_false=0x7f0d0000;
My app is crashing on the above line. Aftre i setup the config to hindi language.

Comment: @ManishAgrawal: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve]. Since it does not appear possible to crash on an `int` variable declaration, make sure that your [mvce] includes the complete Java stack trace and all of your source code that is referenced in that stack trace.