# How to resolve identifier expected error in Resoure file

Tags: android, android-source, r.java-file, custom-rom

Getting error like below

```
out/target/common/obj/APPS/MtkSystemUI_intermediates/srcjars/android/arch/core/R.java:13911: error: <identifier> expected
    public static final int 1=0x7f0d0000;
                           ^
out/target/common/obj/APPS/MtkSystemUI_intermediates/srcjars/android/arch/lifecycle/R.java:13911: error: <identifier> expected
    public static final int 1=0x7f0d0000;
                           ^
out/target/common/obj/APPS/MtkSystemUI_intermediates/srcjars/android/arch/lifecycle/extensions/R.java:13911: error: <identifier> expected
    public static final int 1=0x7f0d0000;
```

Can any one tell me what does this error mean.

I am making changes in AOSP code itself for Quick Settings.

Seek any help on this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [public static final int 13687=0x7f020000; Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061466/public-static-final-int-13687-0x7f020000-error)

Answer (score 0):

A variable name must not start with a digit. You have to rename your variable:

```java
public static final int myvar1=0x7f0d0000;
```